# Animated symbol is flickering while moving Mapbox

Tags: android, animation, navigation, mapbox, flicker

I'm using Mapbox in the Android application. I'm trying to move an icon (car icon) along a line. I'm succeeding with the movement itself, but the icon is flickering as it moves along the line.

I looked for a lot of references online and saw that there is a bug in Mapbox SDK for Mobile. But, I think the problem is the rate at which I'm moving the icon.

I'm animating the movement with a **2000ms** duration.

Any help or reference will be good. I'm struggling with finding a solution.

**This is the code for animate the movement**:

```
fun easeSymbolAndAddTrace(
    symbol: Symbol,
    symbolManager: SymbolManager,
    animators: ArrayList<ValueAnimator>,
    location: LatLng,
    rotation: Float,
    points: ArrayList<Point>,
    geoJsonSource: GeoJsonSource,
    duration: Long
) {
    val originalPosition: LatLng = symbol.latLng
    val originalRotation: Float = symbol.iconRotate
    val changeLocation = originalPosition.distanceTo(location) > 3
    val changeRotation = (originalRotation + 150) % 360 >= (rotation + 360) % 360 || (originalRotation + 210) % 360 <= (rotation + 360) % 360
    var nextPosition: LatLng = location

    Log.d("Utils", "original rotation: $originalRotation, rotation: $rotation")

    if (!changeRotation && !changeLocation) {
        return
    }

    val moveSymbol = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f).setDuration(duration)
    moveSymbol.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
    moveSymbol.addUpdateListener { animation: ValueAnimator ->
        if (symbolManager.annotations.indexOfValue(symbol) < 0) {
            return@addUpdateListener
        }

        val fraction = animation.animatedValue as Float
        if (changeLocation) {
            val lat = (location.latitude - originalPosition.latitude) * fraction + originalPosition.latitude
            val lng = (location.longitude - originalPosition.longitude) * fraction + originalPosition.longitude
            nextPosition = LatLng(lat, lng)
            symbol.geometry = Point.fromLngLat(lng, lat)
            // Adding a trace to the next position.
            // This trace will be shown along the all animation, of the car icon moving.
            addTrace(originalPosition, nextPosition, points, geoJsonSource)
        }

        if (changeLocation && changeRotation) {
            val rotate = (rotation - originalRotation) * fraction + originalRotation
            symbol.iconRotate = if ((originalRotation + 360) % 360 < (rotation + 360) % 360) {
                rotation
            } else {
                rotate
            }
            Log.d("Utils", "icon rotate: ${symbol.iconRotate}")
        }

        symbolManager.update(symbol)
    }

    moveSymbol.start()
    animators.add(moveSymbol)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix for this issue is to allow icon overlap of the symbol you are animating. Add the line `PropertyFactory.iconAllowOverlap(true)` where you are specifying the properties for the respective SymbolLayer.

The underlying bug seems to be related to [this issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/6052).